# Warning: The connection is going to be closed but there is an active transaction

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, cakephp-3.0

My controller code is structured in this way:

```
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$connection->begin();

try {
   //Some logic here to create entities, validate and save them
   //This code can throw exceptions

   $connection->commit();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
   $connection->rollback();
}
```

Is this a correct way to use transactions in CakePHP? If an exception indeed is thrown, the transaction is correctly rolled back, but a warning appears:

`Warning: The connection is going to be closed but there is an active transaction.`

I suppose, I miss an important point somewhere, because I don't understand why this warning is issued. I always thought, either `commit()` or `rollback()` would close a transaction. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I've been trying to find the cause of this problem since 2 or 3 months now, and just after I had asked this question, I've found it! **This is Stackoverflow magic, everyone.**

My exception was never caught, because I missed the `\` in the `catch` directive. Since my code lives in a controller, PHP assumed to only catch an `App\Controller\Exception` (default controller namespace). To catch all exceptions, the code must be

`catch (\Exception $e) {`

Easy.

Comment: You might also be interested in the [transactional](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#using-transactions) function, which can wrap up the begin/commit/rollback stuff for you.